# iPad UIModalPresentationPageSheet top 40 pixels cut off

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I was using a FormSheet style modal view, but in order to show more information, I am switching to a PageSheet. When I change my code to this:

```
targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
```

I get this (notice the top red bar is cut off):

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` will give you the height of the **screen**.

> The height of the presented view is set to the height of the screen and...

This is different from the *available* height for the user interface. You can either hide the  status bar, like:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = true;
```

and make the screen's height equals to the available UI height **or** subtract the status bar height from your frame.